# I need to do border image for website. Usign css code. But i don't know the dimensions

Tags: css, border, dimensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AS65T.png)

For exemple this image is 81x81px.
So i need to draw border, but the question is "what are the dimensions of final product"?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing an example of your code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

According to what I understood from what you said I think that you don't need to know the height and weight of the picture because CSS will do the work for you ... all what you need is to add this css code :

```
img{ border : 5px solid #555; }
```

you can costumize it as you want .